# Как спарсить текст класса и вывести его в абзаце?

Tags: javascript, html

Как спарсить текст класса и вывести его в абзаце?

```html
<h1 class="title-value">Заголовок</h1>

<p class="paste-here"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что хотите спарсить. 
Текст из поля, или название класса& 
Добавил и то и то.

```js
    window.onload = function () { // При загрузке документа
        let title = document.getElementsByClassName('title-value'); // Ищем поле с классом title-value
        let classTitle = title[0].className; // Получаем имя класса
        let p = document.getElementsByClassName('paste-here'); // Получаем поле с классом paste-here что вставить туда данные
        p[0].innerHTML = "Класс поля - "+classTitle+". Текст поля - "+title[0].innerHTML; // Добавляем данные
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="title-value">Заголовок</h1>

<p class="paste-here"></p>
```

Comment: Не это ищите? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery/926633#926633